# python telethon open special link programably

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

There is a wiki page https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Special-links about special links `tg://` | `https://t.me/..` and etc. Is it a way to open **any** type of that links it via `telethon` python non-bot client without selenium usage?

Comment: Nope, there is no builtin way to *react* to those links. They're there for documentation purposes, since, as a bot, you may want to send them to your users.

Comment: You can try to parse them.